# Node.js & Socket.IO - Rooms issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

Considering a multi-chat application.
Users can join multiple rooms ( `socket.join(room)` ), users can leave a room ( `socket.leave(room)` ).

When socket is leaving a room I notify the other room participants. If the socket is currently in 3 rooms, and he suddenly disconnects from the website without leaving the rooms the proper way, how can I notify those rooms that the user has left ?

If I work with the on socket disconnect event, the user will no longer be in any room at that point. Is the only way keeping a separate array of users, or is there some clever way I haven't thought about?

Comment: hmm, no matter what i seem to do there is always 2 users in the room according to socketio

Answer (score 5, accepted):

During the disconnect event the socket is still available to your process. For example, this should work

```
io.socket.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.on('disconnect', function() {
       // this returns a list of all rooms this user is in
       var rooms = io.sockets.manager.roomClients[socket.id];
       for(var room in rooms) {
           socket.leave(room);
       }
    });
});
```

Although this is not actually necessary as socket.io will automatically prune [rooms](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/wiki/Rooms) upon a disconnect event. However this method could be used if you were looking to perform a specific action.

Comment: how about using the window.onbeforeunload in the client browser ? Do you think it will be unstable ?

Comment: You could do that, but I dont think there would be much of a point. Your trying to alert the other users in a given room that this person has left. The view of the particular client has no effect on any of the others, so the only useful thing you could do is trigger some socket event which then tells all of the other users that they left. It would be better to keep it on the server and use the disconnect event.

Comment: I don't quite understand the first part of you answer... what if the rooms are created dynamical ? do I have to create a io.of(./room1).on for each of them ?

Comment: My first answer was off. you wouldn't want to do `io.of(./room1).on(...)` unless you were treating rooms as namespaces. Instead you can just call `socket.leave(room)` on the disconnect event but the [documentation](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/wiki/Rooms) points out that this will happen automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that socket is a long lived object in your node process. If that's the case then you could easily add a reference to the user on your socket object when the user connects. When you get a socket disconnect, you don't need to look up the user the session is associated with as it will be there.

on connection or login:

```
socket.user = yourUser;
```

on disconnect:

```
socket.on('disconnect', function(){
  socket.leave(room, socket.user);
}
```

see here for an example of adding properties to the socket object and a single room chat client:

http://psitsmike.com/2011/09/node-js-and-socket-io-chat-tutorial/

Comment: A socket is a socket.io session...nothing more ( socket.id )